# WordPress. wp_nav_menu(), можно ли li который имеет вложенность, задать свой класс?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

До этого было статическое меню, теперь переделываю под обычное wp меню. У li который содержал вложенный ul, был свой класс, на котором завязывались все действия. Можно ли методами wp задавать данный класс всем li, которые имеют вложенность?

Comment: стандартное WP menu  автоматом задаёт класс для LI у которых имеются вложенность, насколько помню класс называется
 menu-item-has-children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли методами wp задавать данный класс всем li, которые имеют вложенность?

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо) это именно оно)