# Как добавить свой класс к элементам меню и ссылкам в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый вечер, подскажите как сделать вывод своих классов к элементам li и a.
По дефолту выводятся стандартные классы, могу ли я как-то к ним добавить свои? Для li .main-menu__item для а .main-menu__link

```
         <nav class="main-menu">
          <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
                'menu' => 'top_menu' , 
                'container' => 'false' , 
                'menu_class' => 'row between' 
            ) ); ?>
          <!--<ul class="row between">
            <li class="main-menu__item">
              <a class="main-menu__link" href="page1.html">Page1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-menu__item">
              <a class="main-menu__link" href="page2.html">Page2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-menu__item">
              <a class="main-menu__link" href="page3.html">Page3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>-->
        </nav>
```

Comment: это что ли? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630778/wordpress-wp-nav-menu-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-li-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0/630786#630786

Comment: )) ну не совсем, я бы хотел на стороне php это сделать, через админку можно прицепиться только к одному елементу, я хочу прицепить класс к тегу li и к тегу a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого есть 2 фильтра, которые надо добавить в functions.php.

Первый фильтрует классы элементов `<li>`

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'nav_css_filter' );
function nav_css_filter( $classes ){
    // Здесь добавить или убрать классы...
    return $classes;
}
```

Второй фильтрует элементы `<a>`

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'nav_link_filter', 10, 4 );
function nav_link_filter( $atts, $item, $args, $depth ){
    // Здесь изменить атрибуты <a>...
    return $atts;
}
```

Comment: Супер!! спасибо огромное, одной головной болью меньше.